# Can't change lock screen wallpaper

Tags: greeter, wallpaper

```
[greeter]
#activate-numlock=true
#default-wallpaper=/usr/share/backgrounds/164.jpg
#high-contrast=false
#onscreen-keyboard=false
#screensaver-timeout=60
```

I modified the panthon-greeter.config but still my lock screen wallpaper is the same and why does it say default wallpaper and doesn't differentiate between lock screen and background wallpaper. How can i keep them separate ??
I am using Loki

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "164.jpg" is exist in /usr/share/backgrounds?

Comment: Yes, I rechecked and confirmed that it exists

Comment: I have another question, when I checked the default-background link points to a different image than the one I have as my current background. What does the default signify. How is the wallpaper changed and stored when changed via GUI

Answer (score 0):

> How can i keep them separate ?

Quite simple, but not as intuitive unfortunately.

All images used as wallpaper from **/usr/share/backgrounds** will be applied by LOKI to both Desktop and Login (permissions matter too!)

To keep them separate, use an image from **/usr/share/backgrounds** as your login BG with greeter config line (must be unhashed!):

```
default-wallpaper=/usr/share/backgrounds/YOURCHOSENBG.jpg
```

And to set different wall for the destop only, choose an image from any other location in the system, and use right clik->set as wallpaper - that should keep them separate. Tested it on JUNO Beta2 and it works.

Setting desktop wallpaper this way copies your chosen image to **/home/YOURUSER/.local/share/backgrounds/** and imports it to Settings->Desktop->Wallpaper. This unfortunate way, its up to you to remember which image is from here...

**/usr/share/backgrounds** (applies to both Desktop and Login)

or here...

**/home/YOURUSER/.local/share/backgrounds/** (applies to Desktop only)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this, but I had to. A lot of people are looking for the solution.

[How to change the grey background on lock screen in Elementary OS - two videos which explain the below method](https://sysadmin.info.pl/en/how-to-change-the-grey-background-on-lock-screen-in-elementary-os/)

Full solution below:

Tested on Hera 5.1

Downloaded this: https://github.com/elementary/greeter/archive/master.zip

from https://github.com/elementary/greeter/

Extracted the zip to /tmp

I opened terminal, sudo -i, typed root password. Then run gimp as root (just type gimp in terminal), saved jpg file as png in greeter-master/data folder (replaced previous texture.png file).

Edited the SystemBackground.vala file located in /tmp/greeter-master/compositor/

sudo vi /tmp/greeter-master/compositor/SystemBackground.vala

Changed path from:
var texture_file = GLib.File.new_for_uri ("resource:///io/elementary/desktop/gala/texture.png");

to:
var texture_file = GLib.File.new_for_uri ("resource:///io/elementary/greeter/texture.png");
Installed all dependencies listed here:

https://github.com/elementary/greeter/blob/master/README.md

gnome-settings-daemon >= 3.27
how to check version in terminal:
sudo gnome-control-center --version

Very important:

#

Installed dependencies:

sudo apt install -y libaccountsservice-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgranite-dev libgtk-3-dev liblightdm-gobject-1-dev libwingpanel-2.0-dev libx11-dev meson valac libmutter-2-0 libmutter-2-dev

#

Compiled as root

cd /tmp/greeter-master

meson build --prefix=/usr

cd build

ninja

ninja install